# Divs won't position right.

Tags: html, css, position

I am sorry for the "noob" question but it's driving me crazy...

```
<div id="footer">
        <div id="footer_wrapper">
            <div id="project_wrapper">
                <div class="footer_image_div project 1">
                    <p>Axance</p>
                    <img src="/axance/img/upload/small/1336465127.jpg" class="footer_image" alt="" />
                    <div class="info_div">
                        <a href="/axance/projects/view/3">Lees meer...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_image_div project 2">
                    <p>Axance</p>
                    <img src="/axance/img/upload/small/1336465159.jpg" class="footer_image" alt="" />
                    <div class="info_div">
                        <a href="/axance/projects/view/4">Lees meer...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_image_div project 3">
                    <p>Dit is een test</p>
                    <img src="/axance/img/upload/small/1336481215.png" class="footer_image" alt="" />
                    <div class="info_div">
                        <a href="/axance/projects/view/5">Lees meer...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer_image_div project 4">
                    <p>Test project</p>
                    <img src="/axance/img/upload/small/1336564574.jpg" class="footer_image" alt="" />
                    <div class="info_div">
                        <a href="/axance/projects/view/6">Lees meer...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the style sheet:

```
    #footer_wrapper {
      margin-bottom:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-top:auto;
      width:1000px;
    }

#footer_wrapper {
  margin-bottom:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:auto;
  width:1000px;
}
.project {
  height:220px;
  width:270px;
}
style.css (line 105)
.footer_image_div {
  float:left;
  padding-left:21.66666666666667px;
  padding-right:21.66666666666667px;
}
```

Now what i want is that all the 4 DIVS are in the `project_wrapper` (in line) and that only 3 are displayed and the other is hidden outside the div.
How do I manage this?

Again I am sorry for the noob question and the long information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div widths + the margins you have on them add up to more than 1000px and is forcing the last div onto the next line (outside the div).

if you change the width of .project to:

```
.project {
  height:220px;
  width:200px;
 }
```

they will all fit on one line like so: http://jsfiddle.net/v57n3/

Alternatively you can tailor the margins on the first and last divs by adding extra classes like. or you can reduce the margin on .footer_image_div

```
.first{ margin-left:0px;}
```

or

```
.last{ margin-right:0px;}
```

This explains the box model. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: This will result in displaying them all in the wrapper div. But is there a way to hide the other divs (even if they add up above 1000px) right outside the div?

Comment: you need to add a second container inside, set the width at greater 1000px and then set the overflow of the original container as hidden.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v57n3/2/ like this

Answer (score 0):

the width of all your project divs added together are more than the width of the container